# BTS 2014 Highway Performance Monitoring System over 2gb dbf limit

Tags: dbf

http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/2014/polyline

The dbf in question is part of the hpms.shp

The error I receive when trying to import it into postgis (either via shp2pgsql or ogr2ogr) is an fread(782) error. Basically the size of the unzipped dbf file is a bit over 2gb, which is known limitation.

Anyone know how to get around the limitation?

I've contacted the BTS to let them know about this issue...

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate whether the dBase file that you are encountering this on is part of a shapefile, please?  Also, to prevent the need for us to download the *.zip, can you specify what you are doing with it and how this limitation manifests for you - perhaps there is an error message that you can include in your question.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108670/how-can-i-work-with-very-large-shapefiles-1-gb-in-qgis

Comment: I'm not certain that will work. The stated file size limitation on dbf is 2gb.