# Using intersection tool with geodatabase and vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, intersection, esri-geodatabase, error

I want to use the intersection tool in QGIS version 2.18 for two layers:

1. Corine land use data downloaded from: http://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc-2012 (a geodatabase, vector format)
2. buffer layer in vector format.

When I try to use the intersection tool, I get an error:

> "Input layer A contains invalid geometries (feature 1255). Unable to
>   complete intersection algorithm."

Layer A is the Corine layer.

How can I get rid of this error and use the intersection tool properly?

Comment: Check [this](https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/bad-bad-polygon-fixing-invalid-geometries-with-quantum-gis/). You need to correct invalid features before to apply intersection tool.

Comment: @aldo_tapia Thanks, but for some reason I can't toggle the editing mode for the Corine layer.

Comment: Did you download the Esri Geodatabase or SQL database format?

Comment: @aldo_tapia I downloaded the Esri Geodatabase format.

Comment: You can select what you want to use (based on layer B extent) and go to `save as` using `save selected features` and create a new vector layer. After this, you can edit the new layer and delete invalid geometries (you also can use [Topology Checker Plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html) to identify those errors)

Comment: @aldo_tapia I tried creating a new vector layer, but got another error message: [http://oi68.tinypic.com/2v2intg.jpg](http://oi68.tinypic.com/2v2intg.jpg).

Comment: seems to be too big fot the selected format. If you selected shapefile as output format, [consider this].(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108670/how-can-i-work-with-very-large-shapefiles-1-gb-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got over my problems.
Downgrading to QGIS 2.14 Essen helped me get rid of the invalid geometry problems (for some reason using the tips here: https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/bad-bad-polygon-fixing-invalid-geometries-with-quantum-gis/ didn't get rid of all the problems) and then I used clip function instead of intersection.

Also, I had some problems with changing projections and I finally figured out that changing layer CRS does not work as I wanted, but saving a new file with the projection I want worked. :)

Oh, and if anyone is doing something similar with Corine, it might be worth to check that you don't have any features in multiple buffer zones (happens if the buffers are really close). In that case you can use multipart to singleparts function.